# Connecting android device to WiFi hotspot, created on another device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, wifi

I have two android devices - one is a server, second is a client. I run WiFi hotspot on server (using some external app, like [QuickSettings](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amYBA3un9aw)), and then connect to this hotspot on second device. I have an application which transfers some data between these devices, so I need to get an IP address of the server to be able to create a socket on client. So my question is how can I do that inside my application (not justing by typing the proper IP manually)?

Comment: Just one comment: If you run Android 2.2+ you do not need any external application to have a hotspot, since such feature is already included in the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assuming the hotspot is the first IP in the valid range?

I mean: The hotspot gives you device an IP and a mask (and it should give even a gateway). The IP of the hotspot is the IP gateway, but if the hostspot did not tell your device such IP, the gateway is usually the first IP in the range allowed by the mask.